# Unity crash after upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: 16.04, unity, lubuntu, 16.10

After upgrading my system to 16.10 version of Ubuntu, my Unity crashed. I installed now `lubuntu-desktop` and it is working somehow. I want to get rid of lubuntu and have my Unity working. What can I do?

Comment: Please re-install unity

Comment: I already tried with sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop but lubuntu is still starting each time I reboot.

Comment: when you start in the login console you should see it as an option. Please look again, and also do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`

Comment: Please could add a screen shot of the console, if possible

Comment: I also installed lxde, but I think now I have a bad mixed here. In the login I can not choose multiple options. Seems the same after reinstalled unity: http://imgur.com/a/sD8bs

Comment: When I click on the red button in right-top corner to log out I receive this: http://imgur.com/a/mgzbI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59682/discussion-between-george-and-ghitab).

Comment: Please shut down the system from the power button and start it up again

Comment: Ok. Let us continue on chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (as George helped me) was:
I run: 
`sudo apt-cache show lxde`
to see what are the dependencies for lxde.

Then

`sudo apt-get purge lxde`

`sudo apt-get purge gnome*`

`sudo apt-get purge lxde-*`

`sudo apt autoremove`

`sudo apt install unity`

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Added etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf with contents

```
[SeatDefaults] 
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

to restore my login screen. Also upgraded to 17.04.